# Adding multiple model to a store then calling store.sync does not save all the data

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am building a web application using ExtJS4 and I have a part there where I create multiple models then add them to a store then sync the store. However, upon calling `store.sync()`, I see a blank database entry.

My code goes as such:

```
this.mon(uploadDialog, 'uploadcomplete', function(uploadPanel, manager, items, errorCount) {

    var itemCount = items.length;

    for(var i = 0 ; i < itemCount ; i++){
        pathArray.push(items[i].getName());
    }

    console.log('---------- pathArray count = ' + pathArray.length);

    var galleryStore = Ext.getStore('userProfileGallery');
    var userStore = Ext.getStore('userStore');
    var userModel = userStore.first();

    //------------ Iterate through the items, create a model, then add model to the store

    for(var j = 0 ; j < itemCount ; j++){
        var personPhotoModel = Ext.ModelManager.create({
        }, 'myappName.model.userPhoto');

        var currentdate = new Date();

        var uploadDate = currentdate.getDate() + "/" +
            (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" +
            currentdate.getFullYear();

        var uploadTime = currentdate.getHours() + ":" +
            currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" +
            currentdate.getSeconds();

        personPhotoModel.set("image_path", "gallery/" + pathArray[j]);
        personPhotoModel.set("description", "Gallery Image");
        personPhotoModel.set("upload_date", uploadDate);
        personPhotoModel.set("upload_time", uploadTime);
        personPhotoModel.set("user_id", userModel.get('user_id'));

        galleryStore.add(personPhotoModel);
        console.log('gallery store count = ' + galleryStore.count());

    }

    //---------- sync the store here

    console.log('gallery store count = ' + galleryStore.count());

    galleryStore.sync();

}, this);
```

What I've tried so far is to only make 1 model by uploading only one file and that works just fine. However, when I add more than 1 model to the store then sync the store, I get a single blank row regardless of how many items I added to the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see directly why your code doesn't work as expected but I see a lot of room for improvements:

- `Ext.ModelManager.create` is *deprecated* use `Ext.create('Your Model', data);`
- application name and class name start with upper case!
- avoid declaring variables in loops (the date isn't gonna change while looping...)
- declare date in the creation of the model (quicker) else use `record.beginEdit()`, `record.endEdit()` for batch edits. this prevents events from firing every `set`

Here is what I would make of it:

```
this.mon(uploadDialog, 'uploadcomplete', function (uploadPanel, manager, items, errorCount) {

    var itemCount = items.length,
        now = new Date(),
        uploadDate = Ext.Date.format(now, 'd/m/Y'),
        uploadTime = Ext.Date.format(now, 'H:i:s'),
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        pathArray.push(items[i].getName());
    }

    console.log('---------- pathArray count = ' + pathArray.length);

    var galleryStore = Ext.getStore('userProfileGallery'),
        userStore = Ext.getStore('userStore'),
        user = userStore.first();

    //------------ Iterate through the items, create a model, then add model to the store

    for (i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {

        galleryStore.add(Ext.create('MyappName.model.UserPhoto', {
            image_path: "gallery/" + pathArray[i],
            description: "Gallery Image",
            upload_date: uploadDate,
            upload_time: uploadTime,
            user_id: user.get('user_id')
        }));

        console.log('gallery store count = ' + galleryStore.count());
    }

    //---------- sync the store here

    console.log('gallery store count = ' + galleryStore.count());

    galleryStore.sync();

}, this);
```

If this doesn't work your error is not in this piece of code, but in the store, model or backend